# Apache Camel URL Escaping with space

Tags: url, apache-camel, escaping, space, apache-servicemix

I have a simple Camel Route which processes the incoming Http request and then routes to other Http consumers based on the Resource path. Everything works fine but I hit the java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path when used a space in the path. 
Other special characters seem to work fine.

I am building a RESTful APIs and currently using the browser to test my APIs.

Here is the Spring DSL of my route:

```
<route id="API">
   <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0/api?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
   <bean ref="basicAuthBean"/>
   <choice>
     <when>
       <simple>${in.header.CamelHttpPath} contains 'blah1'</simple>
       <to uri="http://localhost:10001/api?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
     </when>
      <when>
       <simple>${in.header.CamelHttpPath} contains 'blah2'</simple>
       <to uri="http://localhost:10002/api?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
     </when>
   </choice>
</route>
```

I enabled trace on the Camel Context and found that the CamelHttpPath had already replaced the escape character "%20" with a space. I also saw that there was CamelHttpUri which had not escaped the special character.

As a hack in my Spring DSL I added the following before the choice element:

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpPath">
  <simple>${in.header.CamelHttpUri}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

This solved my problem but I am pretty sure there is a better way to do this.  Did I miss setting some properties or is my route DSL not accurate?

Also, what is the difference between the CamelHttpPath and CamelHttpUri?

I should also mention that I am using the Camel Context in Apache ServiceMix 4.4.2 and the Camel Version used is 2.8.5.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we have fixed this in later Camel releases due to be released like Camel 2.10.4 etc. I remember working on that space fix.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5504

As Camel 2.8.x is no longer supported you would need to patch the issue yourself. 
Or upgrade to ServiceMix 4.5.0 which includes Camel 2.10.3.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think Service 4.5 is not yet released to public. I will live with my workaround till then.